# How to append something like ?id=1 to a NSMutableURLRequest

Tags: swift, parameters, nsmutableurlrequest

I want to display the data from this URL:
`http://www.football-data.org/soccerseasons/351/fixtures?timeFrame=n14`

My baseURL is `let baseUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.football-data.org")!`,

so my request is `let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: baseUrl.URLByAppendingPathComponent("soccerseasons/" + "\(league.id)" + "/fixtures?timeFrame=n14"))`

But the `?timeFrame=n14` doesn't work.

Anyone knows how to solve this so I can display that data?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is that the question mark in `?timeFrame=n14` is treated as part of the URL's
*path* and therefore HTML-escaped as `%3F`. This should work:

```
let baseUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.football-data.org")!
let url = NSURL(string: "soccerseasons/" + "\(league.id)" + "/fixtures?timeFrame=n14", relativeToURL:baseUrl)!
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
```

Alternatively, use `NSURLComponents`, which lets you build an URL successively from individual components (error checking omitted for brevity):

```
let urlComponents = NSURLComponents(string: "http://www.football-data.org")!
urlComponents.path = "/soccerseasons/" + "\(league.id)" + "/fixtures"
urlComponents.query = "timeFrame=n14"

let url = urlComponents.URL!
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
```

---

**Update for Swift 3:**

```
var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: "http://www.football-data.org")!
urlComponents.path = "/soccerseasons/" + "\(league.id)" + "/fixtures"
urlComponents.query = "timeFrame=n14"

let url = urlComponents.url!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
```

Comment: Yes, that's the answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks Martin, this is great